# prevent array in string field - XSS

Tags: php, arrays, forms, validation, xss

I'm having trouble analyzing input forms...
I will give three examples , both taking into account the change of the form 'User'

---

```
<form method="POST" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" value="Albert">
    <input type="text" name="last_name" value="Einstein">
</form>
```

<sup>original fields unchanged, get the data:

$_POST = array( 'first_name' => 'Albert' , 'last_name' => 'Einstein' )</sup>

---

```
<form method="POST" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="first_name[]" value="Albert">
    <input type="text" name="last_name[]" value="Einstein">
</form>
```

<sup>adulterated fields, I get the data:

$_POST = array( 'first_name' => array( Albert ) , 'last_name' => array( Einstein ) )</sup>

---

```
<form method="POST" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="first_name[]" value="Albert">
    <input type="text" name="first_name[]" value="Einstein">
</form>
```

<sup>adulterated fields, I get the data:

$_POST = array( 'first_name' => array( Albert , Einstein ) , 'last_name' => null )</sup>

---

1. I check if the field is of a type expected even before dealing with the 'class Validate'?
   field_X if a string is as expected and I get an array , I mark it as a mistake or get the first element of the array?
2. If I receive an array into a string field that must be how I'll fill out the form with the data sent ?
   If I complete the field with `$_POST['XXX']` appears `Array`

I hope I have been clear since it is a real problem
Tanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to validate that the input is not an array at the top of your script

```
if(isset($_POST['my_field'] AND !is_array($_POST['my_field'])) {
  $field = htmlentities($_POST['field'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  // You are now "safe"
}
```

1. You need to make sure your response header Content-Type contains "UTF-8" after application/* 
   If your response is not UTF-8, you are vulnerable. Always output strings in UTF-8. You can probably add some UTF-8 validation after the first line in the above script.

Comment: about pattern: when an array I should find the value within the array or advertise a type error?

Comment: Either send the request as an array or not. If you don't choose to send the data as an array, then do not look for the value in the array, as it is not necessary because I am assuming you have complete control over the intended request medium. It is not appropriate to allow a dynamic request. There is no advantage over using arrays in this case. Do not advertise a type error, just show a 404, or a general error message not giving the hacker much to work with.

Comment: solves a generic message ... this problem occurred while testing my validation class, I think I'll have to create a rule for types.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `gettype()` for type validation.

form.html:

```
<form method="POST" action="action.php">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" value="Albert">
    <input type="text" name="last_name" value="Einstein">
</form>
```

action.php

```
<?php

if (gettype($_POST['first_name']) === 'string') {
    var_dump($_POST['first_name']);
}
```

In this example, $_POST['first_name'] is only `var_dump()`ed if it is a string.

Comment: Friend, you do not understand. the `first_name` field must be string, but the field can be changed to `name=first_name[]`, which makes an array value, thanks

Comment: Oh I see, you're talking about a request forgery. You can just add type validation to your list of validations with `gettype()`.

Comment: GetType not necessarily the problem with array type is critical, then I think the best option would be `is_array`. is_array is true and when I find the value within the array or advertise a type error? this part is about standard